# How to dynamically store Select-String matches in an array Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm coming from a PERL background and PowerShell is just confusing me. I have a switch configuration and I'm trying to determine if a config is present when it shouldn't be.

Short example:

```
//BAD interface has maximum of 2 but Only 1 learned
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 2
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky 0050.7966.6800
 switchport port-security
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
 spanning-tree portfast edge
! 
//GOOD default maximum is 1
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky 0050.7966.6801
 switchport port-security
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
 spanning-tree portfast edge
```

The '//' lines above aren't in the actual file. So the "config block" would be from "^interface.... until !"

Here is the code I have so far.

```
$ints = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@() 
$file = Get-Content .\router.txt | Out-String
$file | Select-String -Pattern "(?s)interface [etfg][^!]+!" -AllMatches | foreach {$ints.Add($_.Matches.Value)}
```

I'm trying to add all config blocks to a list to iterate through later and find the "maximum command".

However the above code isn't doing what I expected:

```
$ints.Count
1
```

is there a better way to store all of the "Select-String" matches into a list?

my next step is :

```
foreach ($int in $ints) {
if interface configuration contains shutdown, next iteration
else 
if maximum \d is present, check if there are the same amount of 
mac-sticky commands, if it doesnt it's a violation and store
it for writing a file later.
```

I'm going to run this on ~1000 configuration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the original code  "out-string" placed everything into 1 string, not an array. so when i searched matches it was just one string worth of matches

below code cuts it up

```
$file = Get-Content .\router.txt | Out-String
$ints = $file | Select-String -Pattern "(?s)\ninterface [etfg][^!]+!" -AllMatches | foreach {$_.Matches.Value}
foreach ($line in $ints.split("!")) { 
    if ($line -match 'maximum\s*([0-9]+)') {
        $allowedMacs = $matches[1]
        if ($allowedMacs -gt ($line | Select-String "sticky [\d\w]" -AllMatches).Matches.Count) {
            write-host "Violation!"
        } else {
            write-host "No Violation!"
        }
    }
}
```